# CPU/GPU Memory Usage with Tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, multi-gpu

I want to run a Python script that also uses Tensorflow on a server. When I ran it with no session configuration, the process allocated all of GPU memory, preventing any other process to access to GPU.

The server specs are the following:

- CPU: 2x 12cores@2.5 GHz,
- RAM: 256GB,
- Disks: 2x 240GB SSD, 6x 4TB@7200RPM,
- GPU: 2x Nvidia Titan X.

This server is shared among other colleagues, so I am not really allowed to allocate all of the GPU memory.

On the website of Tensorflow, I found out these instructions to set a threshold to the used GPU memory.

```
config = tf.ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
session = tf.Session(config=config, ...)
```

I have two questions regarding these:
1. If the allocated GPU memory is not enough, will the process automatically use the CPU instead, or will it crash ?
2. What happens if a process wants to use the GPU but the GPU is already fully allocated ?

Thank you.

Comment: Use cuda visible devices env var to allocate one gpu and have coworker allocate another. Tensorflow doesnt do well with multiple processes using same gpu

Answer (score 2):

1. If the allocated GPU memory is not enough TF will throw an Out Of Memory error and crash.
2. TF will also crash in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow provides a few options as alternatives to its default behavior of allocating all available GPU memory (which it does to avoid memory fragmentation and operate more efficiently). These options are:

- `config.gpu_options.allow_growth` - when configured to `True` will dynamically allocate more memory as needed, but will never release memory
- `config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` - when configured to a double between 0 and 1, will statically allocate only that fraction of available memory instead of all memory

See https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/using_gpu#allowing_gpu_memory_growth for more detail.